VS Code(1.94.2)"Go To Definition" (Ctrl+Click) Not Working for SpecFlow Steps
I'm facing a persistent issue with Visual Studio Code where the "Go To Definition" functionality (Ctrl+Click) doesn't work for SpecFlow steps. Despite successful test execution, the IDE fails to locate the corresponding step definitions. This significantly hinders development efficiency and understanding of the test flow.
Key Points:

Test cases are executing without issues.

The problem seems to be specific to VS Code's navigation feature.

"Go To Definition" works for other methods and functions.

I'm using Appium for mobile automation.


Extensions Used:

.NET Tool Kit

Appium

Appium Kit

Appium Toolbox for VS Code

C#

C# Dev Kit

C# Extensions

Cucumber

Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support

Cucumber Quick

Cucumber Step Definition Generator

Feature Syntax Highlight and Snippets

Snippets and Syntax Highlight for Gherkin Cucumber

SpecFlow Steps Definition Generator

SpecFlow Tools


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Disabled all Cucumber-related extensions.

Checked VS Code settings for experimental features and C# language service configuration.

Restarted VS Code.

Reindexed the workspace.

Cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Updated VS Code and extensions.



Did you follow the steps outlined here? https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/vscode/vscode-specflow.html

Update: I resolved it.
I had to add the following configuration in my settings.json.
{   "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [           
    "MobileAutomationFramework/StepDefinitions/*.cs",            
    "MobileAutomationFramework/StepDefinitions/**/*.cs"],        
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "MobileAutomationFramework/Features/*",        
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,       
    "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,         
    "cucumberautocomplete.skipDocStringsFormat": true,
    "dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": []
 }


If this answered your question, go ahead and click the checkmark icon next to it. Nothing wrong with answering your own question. :)
